# List of various IReliableDictionaries

Tags: c#, generics, azure-service-fabric

Using [IReliableDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn971511.aspx) in a Service Fabric application.

Trying to organise all the dictionaries in a class, is there a way to have a list of `IReliableDicionary` that use different keys?

```
IReliableDictionary<Guid, User>   x = await GetDictionaryAsync<Guid, User>("userDict");
IReliableDictionary<string, Guid> y = await GetDictionaryAsync<string, Guid>("emailToUser");

var dicts = new List<IReliableDictionary<object, object>> { x, y };
```

Only this doesn't work, because the key of `IReliableDictionary` has to implement `IComparable` and `IEquatable`.

Not had that much experience with Generics in C#. Could think of how to do this in java, with `? extends` notation. Is this possible in C#?

Comment: I notice that your keys are `string` and `guid`. Wouldn't it be simpler to uniformly use string as converting guid to string is simple?

Comment: And what are you going to do next with that list? I mean if that somehow worked, you still need to know types of keys and values to be able to use that dictionary later.

Comment: @MaorVeitsman Potentially, however was hoping to not have to rewrite large amounts of the service. Additionally this would lose clarity, as well as validation of Guids

Comment: @Evk Yes, but that could be done through reflection. Looking at simplifying the calls to the State Manager.

Comment: If you will use reflection to work with that list anyway, you can as well declare it as List<object>.

Comment: True, however I thought that there's no point using it where it's not necessary. I thought there must be an easy way of doing this that I was somehow not seeing/didn't know.

Comment: Well they both implement IReliableState interface also, so you can use List<IReliableState>, if that would be of any help.

Comment: True, although I was hoping to distinguish between IReliableCollection and IReliableDictionary (and potentially IReliableQueue...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're going with this. You're not going to get the compiler to enforce type safety for the dictionaries in that list. You'll have to write reflection code. You could also run into problems trying to maintain references to the dictionaries yourself.

The StateManager object already manages your dictionaries for you - that's what it's for. The only thing you should need to keep track of yourself is the names of the dictionaries.